# IBM ICU - String conversion functions

Tags: icu

In IBM ICU C library are there any string to number conversion functions. Something like `atoi` and `atoll`.

I am looking for ICU functions for string conversions - Cross platform, cross compiler and 32 and 64 bit version.

1. Function should throw an error. overflow or underflow.
2. I thought using `errno` -- But `errno` is not set in all platforms For Ex: Windows `atoi`.
3. `strtol` --> this function is for long data type. There is no function like `strtoi`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the NumberFormat class (C++)  or unum.h interfaces (C) for string to number (i.e. parsing).  Instead of errno, ICU uses an [error code system (UErrorCode).](http://userguide.icu-project.org/design#TOC-Error-Handling)

HTH